# Wordpress use WP_Query to get product by ID

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get a specific product by its ID in Wordpress using WP_Query and i'm struggling to find the right argument from yesterday. I'm stuck.I'ts from 'product_cat' taxonomy

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'id' => $product_id,
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'=> array($product_id)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Stupid questing but i've found the answer. Kept my brain struggling for so long...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'=> array($id),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function cs_get_cost_transportation( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $productId = $request->get_param( 'productId' );
    $wpq         = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
             'posts_per_page' => 1,
             'post__in'=> array($productId)
    ) );
    $postIds     = $wpq->get_posts();
    $productsFilter_cabin = cs_get_products_for_from_post_ids( $postIds );
    return rest_ensure_response($productsFilter_cabin);

}
```